# Display a permanent OSD

Tags: windows, linux, keyboard-layout, osd

Is there any way to have a permanent static translucent OSD somewhere on my screen? I'm looking for an overlay that I cannot interact with so I can still use whatever is behind it.

What I am trying to get is an always visible overview of an alternative keyboard layout (NEO, some kind of German Dvorak) that won't use any screen estate.

I'm looking for solutions both for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Windows and which Linux?

Does applying a **physical decal** on the screen count? Because that's exactly what you want, actually — unless you plan to edit that layout frequently, in that case I understand this might not be ideal.

When I created [my keyboard layout](https://github.com/Lohoris/IT4) I just **used it as a background**, and doing that worked fine for me because using OSX I had Exposé which had a very handy shortcut for showing the desktop. In Windows you can do the same with Win+Space (thanks @OliverSalzburg).

Comment: Don't know Exposé, but the Windows shortcut Win+Space could come in handy. It lets you *peek* at the desktop.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg good tip!